# Python transfer all data of table to table of different database

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I can connect to a database Postgres with psycopg2, but this just 1 database. I have a problem that use Python code to move data of this table (database No.1) to another table (database No.2). The second database is in the same server. Any suggestions for me?

Comment: The easiest way is to use a [foreign table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createforeigntable.html)  then this gets as simple as an `insert` statement. Or maybe you don't need to replicate the data at all then (you could create the foreign table in database 2 pointing to the table in database 1 - for database 2 it would look like a local table)

Comment: You could also simply export your table (`pg_dump`) from database 1 and import (`psql` or `pg_restore`) to database 2